# I am not getting the filesize of my youtube video in python module pytube

Tags: python, pytube

```
from tkinter import * 
from pytube import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg
video_link = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvpb8IdDZZI&t=187s")
print(video_link.title)
print(video_link.streaming_data)
print(video_link.filesize)
# print(video_link.request.filesize)
video_link.streams.first().download()
video_link.register_on_progress_callback(print("Donwloading...."))
print("Video Downloaded")
```

there is an error coming that no attribute of filesize

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. When posting error messages, please always copy and paste the _exact_, complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

video_link comes with the different video streams & mime_type. Hence each stream are having its own file size. You can get the file size by calling `.filesize` on each stream object.

Have a look at the following code snippet & the output:

```
for stream in video_link.streams:
    print(stream.mime_type, " ->", stream.filesize/(1024*1024), "MB")
```

Output:

```
video/3gpp  -> 2.6263113021850586 MB
video/mp4   -> 11.084802627563477 MB
video/mp4   -> 41.03022003173828 MB
video/mp4   -> 21.231401443481445 MB
video/webm  -> 14.185770988464355 MB
video/mp4   -> 11.328568458557129 MB
video/webm  -> 7.106128692626953 MB
video/mp4   -> 6.5809221267700195 MB
video/webm  -> 4.435785293579102 MB
video/mp4   -> 3.535641670227051 MB
video/webm  -> 2.547992706298828 MB
video/mp4   -> 1.6807842254638672 MB
video/webm  -> 1.6590118408203125 MB
audio/mp4   -> 2.3037548065185547 MB
audio/mp4   -> 6.112131118774414 MB
audio/webm  -> 2.3510265350341797 MB
audio/webm  -> 3.106660842895508 MB
audio/webm  -> 6.124373435974121 MB
```

`filesize` gives you the size of the file in bytes. you can convert it into MB by dividing it by 1024*1024.

PS, if you want to get the size of the highest resolution stream:

```
print(video_link.streams.get_highest_resolution().filesize/1024/1024, "MB")
```

Comment: How can i download in audio mp4 resolution in this

Comment: I found this useful. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pytube-python-library-download-youtube-videos/